# React Sub-path creates error when directly enter the URL in browser

Tags: reactjs

i have the below Route path in my react code.

```
<Route path="/company-group/:action" exact component = {CompanyGroupForm}  />
```

This works fine when  go to the url from my webpage using link  `<Link to="/company-group/add">Add</Link>`

But it gives error if I directly enter the actual path (`http://localhost:8000/company-group/add`) in browser

This is the error I am getting

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

Whats going wrong here

Comment: Can you try modifying ```publicPath``` in the ```webpack.config.js``` file ```output``` like, ```output: { publicPath: '/', }```

Comment: I can't find the webpack.config.js file, i am using laravel react package. where it will be

Comment: If you are using vs code as editor, you can find it out using ```ctrl + p``` then type ```webpack.co....``` .. Else it will be in the same path as ```package.json``` is..